# What is the easiest way to interact with your contract in a development environment?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, tokens

Is there some form of toolkit which generates a console similar to the one on etherscan, where you can call functions that are defined in your contracts ABI?

It seems quite painful having to write the code out in a truffle console

Comment: RemixIDE does it pretty well. Check tab "Deploy & Run transaction"

Comment: Remix.. you copy the contract there, connect remix to ganche or your metamask and deploy it there

Answer (score 0):

I usually write standalone JavaScript and Python snippets in Visual Studio Code and run them from command-line. Somewhat better than Truffle console, because you do the work in a professional code editor. With some effort, especially in the case of Python, you get nice autocompletion.

However, I am not aware of any tool like Etherescan, which would generate web page with automated read/write fields based on the contract ABI.